# Python BeautifulSoup, iterating through tags and attributes

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, tags

I would like to iterate through all the tag I have in certain section of the html page. I applied the BeautifulSoup, but I could live without it and just the Selenium library.
Let's say I have the following html code:

```
<table id="myBSTable">   
    <tr>
        <th>Column A1</th>
        <th>Column B1</th>
        <th>Column C1</th>
        <th>Column D1</th>
        <th>Column E1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data="First Column Data"></td>
        <td data="Second Column Data"></td>
        <td title="Title of the First Row">Value of Row 1</td>
        <td>Beautiful 1</td>
        <td>Soup 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td data-g="Second Column Data"></td>
        <td title="Title of the Second Row">Value of Row 2</td>
        <td>Selenium 1</td>
        <td>Rocks 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td title="Title of the Third Row">Value of Row 3</td>
        <td>Pyhon 1</td>
        <td>Boulder 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Column A2</th>
        <th>Column B2</th>
        <th>Column C2</th>
        <th>Column D2</th>
        <th>Column E2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data="First Column Data"></td>
        <td data="Second Column Data"></td>
        <td title="Title of the First Row">Value of Row 1</td>
        <td>Beautiful 2</td>
        <td>Soup 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td data-g="Second Column Data"></td>
        <td title="Title of the Second Row">Value of Row 2</td>
        <td>Selenium 2</td>
        <td>Rocks 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td title="Title of the Third Row">Value of Row 3 2</td>
        <td>Pyhon 2</td>
        <td>Boulder 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have this part working perfectly:

```
#Selenium libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

#BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://urltoget.com')   

table = browser.find_element_by_id('myBSTable')
bs_table = BeautifulSoup(table.get_attribute('innerHTML'), 'lxml')
#So far so good
rows = bs_table.findAll('tr')
for tr in rows:
    #Here is where I need help
    #I want to iterate through all tags
    #but I don't know if is going to be a th or a td
    #At the same time I need to do something
    #if is a td or a th
```

And this is what I want to accomplish:

```
    #The following is a pseudo code
    for col in tr.tags:
        print col.name, col.value
        for attribute in col.attrs:
            print "    ", attribute.name, attribute.value
    #End pseudo code
```

Thanks,
Arty

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may locate either `td` or `th` by specifying a list of tags to look for. In order to get all element attributes, use [`.attrs` attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

```
rows = bs_table.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cells = row.find_all(['td', 'th'])
    for cell in cells:
        print(cell.name, cell.attrs)
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution almost worked. And I say almost because the cell.attrs did not worked. After a little research I found the following method to iterate through the attributes:**
    `for attr, value in cell.attrs.iteritems():
        print "    attribute", attr, value`**
I had to use the iteritems() from attrs because it doesn't work if I only have cells.attrs.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative looping (action is at the bottom):

```
html='''<table id="myBSTable">   
    <tr>
        <th>Column A1</th>
        <th>Column B1</th>
        <th>Column C1</th>
        <th>Column D1</th>
        <th>Column E1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data="First Column Data"></td>
        <td data="Second Column Data"></td>
        <td title="Title of the First Row">Value of Row 1</td>
        <td>Beautiful 1</td>
        <td>Soup 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td data-g="Second Column Data"></td>
        <td title="Title of the Second Row">Value of Row 2</td>
        <td>Selenium 1</td>
        <td>Rocks 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td title="Title of the Third Row">Value of Row 3</td>
        <td>Pyhon 1</td>
        <td>Boulder 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Column A2</th>
        <th>Column B2</th>
        <th>Column C2</th>
        <th>Column D2</th>
        <th>Column E2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data="First Column Data"></td>
        <td data="Second Column Data"></td>
        <td title="Title of the First Row">Value of Row 1</td>
        <td>Beautiful 2</td>
        <td>Soup 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td data-g="Second Column Data"></td>
        <td title="Title of the Second Row">Value of Row 2</td>
        <td>Selenium 2</td>
        <td>Rocks 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td title="Title of the Third Row">Value of Row 3 2</td>
        <td>Pyhon 2</td>
        <td>Boulder 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>'''

Soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

rows = Soup.findAll('tr')
for tr in rows:
    for z in tr.children:
        if z.name =='td':
            do stuff1
        if z.name == 'th':
            do stuff2
```