# Extract text from html using BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm new to python and BeautifulSoup and need help writing a for loop to retrieve some text values from html.  Also new to stack overflow :-)

I am able to crawl the webpage using the td tag below and find rows which have employees of a  company that I want to add to a list.  Not sure how to write the for loop that will disregard the tags and just retrieve the text value (ie employee names) from each row, and then add that to a new list, employees. So in example below, how do I retrive John Doe, Bob Smith etc and that to a list? Any help appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import re

url = 'my target URL'
target_url= uReq(url)
target_html = target_url.read()
soupy = soup(target_html, 'html.parser')
print(soupy.prettify())


employees = []
employees = soupy.findAll('td', headers= 'table5593r1')
employees

<td headers="'table5593r1"><a href="https://www.acme.org/about-acme/people/john-doe" target="_blank">Mr John Doe</a></td>,
 <td headers="'table5593r1"><a href="https://www.acme.org/about-acme/people/bob-smith">Dr Bob Smith</a></td>,
 <td headers="'table5593r1"><a href="https://www.acme.org/about-acme/people/jane-do">Dr Jane Do</a></td>,
 <td headers="'table5593r1"><a href="https://www.acme.org/about-acme/people/mary-jane">Ms Mary Jane</a></td>,
```

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27934403/13044314) shows how you can get the text of HTML elements/tags. In order to add the employee names to a new list, you could do the following:

```py
employees = soupy.findAll('td', headers= 'table5593r1')
employeeNames = []

for employee in employees:
  employeeName = employee.text
  employeeNames.append(employeeName.strip())
```

I'd also recommend to take a further look into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44723857/13044314) regarding the looping over a list of HTML elements.